# Adding google font api to select menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-font-api

I am making a select box with all the fonts in google fonts API. I have referred this https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/developer_api link to learn more about API but till now i was not able to make it.

I am adding this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekdx/pJHnD/2/) which i made for this.

HTML

```
       <select id="styleFont">
          <option value="0">Myraid Pro</option>
          <option value="1">Sans ref</option>
          <option value="2">Times New Roman</option>
          <option value="3"> Arial</option>
       </select>
 <br>
  <textarea id="custom_text"></textarea>
```

CSS

```
 #custom_text{ resize: none;}​
```

Script

```
      $("#styleFont").change(function () {
     var id =$('#styleFont option' + ':selected').text();    
    $("#custom_text").css('font-family',id);
    });​
```

My API key is https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo

How can i link those fonts to my select box in the fiddle?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @trebuchet i am trying to add the list of Google font API in my select . I have gained my API key which is https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo now i need to connect my select with it

Comment: @trebuchet it worked fine in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ocutuk/9/edit) But when i copy all the code to my html page its not working what is the problem in that or what i have to add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use jquery to get the font list, then add each font to your select:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo", function(fonts){
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i++) {      
     $('#styleFont')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", fonts.items[i].family)
         .text(fonts.items[i].family));
    }    
});
```

**EDIT: This uses JSONP**

```
function SetFonts(fonts) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i++) {      
     $('#styleFont')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", fonts.items[i].family)
         .text(fonts.items[i].family));
    }    
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo&callback=SetFonts';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: will you please look over this http://jsbin.com/ocutuk/1 and spot me where i made the mistake

Comment: ah - I know the issue. Chrome won't let you access an external URL whereas firefox will...

Comment: Thats the problem thanks dude it shows all the text names but not chcnging the font family in the textarea http://jsbin.com/ocutuk/3/

Comment: see my edit - using JSONP makes this work as necessary. as to why your fonts don't load - each google font must be loaded individually. Your code doesn't load any.

Comment: Dude its working http://jsbin.com/ocutuk/3/edit but the problem is the font-family is changing only once

Comment: Please use the updated code I posted - it avoids cross-domain issues and works in all browsers. As for the fonts - they aren't loaded in your code. you must load them each (as per google's instructions at http://www.google.com/webfonts)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20739/discussion-between-vivek-dragon-and-trebuchet)

Comment: it worked fine in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ocutuk/9/edit) But when i copy all the code to my html page its not working what is the problem in that or what i have to add

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, I didn't find anything as good for this as I wanted, so I developed my own selector:

Github https://github.com/maPer77/Select2-Google-Fonts

Demonstration: https://maper77.github.io/Select2-Google-Fonts/

See it working:

```js
selectGfont({
  key: 'AIzaSyDlD2NdRw4MDt-jDoTE_Hz3JqNpl154_qo', 
  containerFonte: '#selectGFont', 
  containerVariante: '#selectGFontVariante',
  sort: 'popularity',
  onSelectFonte: 'sGFselecionado'
 });


sGFselecionado = function(fonte, variante, json){
  console.log( 'fonte', fonte );
  console.log( 'variante', variante );
  console.log( 'json', json );
};
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maper77.github.io/Select2-Google-Fonts/src/selectGfont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.28/webfontloader.js"></script>
<script src="https://maper77.github.io/Select2-Google-Fonts/src/selectGfont.min.js"></script>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
 <!-- Fonte GOOGLE -->
 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-8">
  <label><span class="selectGFontTotal"></span> Google Fonts</label>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
   <select id='selectGFont' data-default='Play' class="form-control invisible"></select>
   <div class="input-group-append">
    <select id='selectGFontVariante' data-default='regular' class="form-control invisible"></select>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Great plugin! works like a charm. May I know if there is any method to set font to the select input in a JavaScript event?