# google web fonts in a DropDown list dynamically with respective Font Weights

Tags: jquery, google-webfonts

I've created a function to add google fonts in a `select`. But I've 2 issues:

1. I had to add all google fonts name manually in a variable `fonts`.
2. I cannot find a way to add `font-weight` that a font supports, as all google font doesn't support all `font-weight` `100-900`

Is there any way I can add the google font's dynamically with respective `font-weights`?

```js
(function ( $ ) { 
  $.fn.webfonts = function(font) {
   var font_set = "";
   font_set = font;

   var fonts = ["ABeeZee","Abel","Abril Fatface","Aclonica","Acme","Actor","Adamina","Advent Pro","Aguafina Script","Akronim","Aladin","Aldrich","Alef","Alegreya","Alegreya SC","Alegreya Sans","Emilys Candy","Engagement","Englebert","Enriqueta","Erica One","Esteban","Euphoria Script","Ewert","Exo","Exo 2","Lato","League Script","Leckerli One","Ledger","Lekton","Lemon","Libre Baskerville","Life Savers","Lilita One","Lily Script One","Limelight","Linden Hill","Lobster","Lobster Two","Londrina Outline","Londrina Shadow","Londrina Sketch","Londrina Solid","Lora","Love Ya Like A Sister","Loved by the King","Lovers Quarrel","Luckiest Guy","Odor Mean Chey","Offside","Old Standard TT","Poly","Pompiere","Pontano Sans","Poppins","Port Lligat Sans","Port Lligat Slab","Pragati Narrow","Prata","Preahvihear","Press Start 2P","Princess Sofia","Prociono","Prosto One","Puritan","Purple Purse","Quando","Quantico","Quattrocento","Quattrocento Sans","Questrial","Quicksand","Quintessential","Qwigley","Racing Sans One","Radley","Rajdhani","Raleway","Raleway Dots","Ramabhadra","Ramaraja","Rambla","Rammetto One","Ranchers","Rancho","Ranga","Rationale","Ravi Prakash","Redressed","Reenie Beanie","Revalia","Rhodium Libre","Ribeye","Ribeye Marrow","Righteous","Risque","Roboto","Roboto Condensed","Roboto Mono","Roboto Slab"];
   var font_preview = 0;
   var font_list = '<option value="">None</option>';

   for (var i=0; i < fonts.length; i++){
       font_list += '<option value="'+ fonts[i] + '">' + fonts[i] + '</option>';
   }

   this.addClass('webfonts').append(font_list);

      $(this).find('option').each(function(){              
             if($(this).val()==font_set ){
                 $(this).attr('selected','selected');
             }
         });
  };    
  
     $('#google-fonts').webfonts();
 }( jQuery ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="google-fonts"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than populating the font list and weights manually, you need to get them through the [Google Fonts Developer API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api):

Calling `https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY` would yield:

```
{
 "kind": "webfonts#webfontList",
 "items": [


[...]

{
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Anonymous Pro",
   "variants": [
    "regular",
    "italic",
    "700",
    "700italic"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "greek",
    "greek-ext",
    "cyrillic-ext",
    "latin-ext",
    "latin",
    "cyrillic"
   ],
   "version": "v3",
   "lastModified": "2012-07-25",
   "files": {
    "regular": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/Zhfjj_gat3waL4JSju74E-V_5zh5b-_HiooIRUBwn1A.ttf",
    "italic": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/q0u6LFHwttnT_69euiDbWKwIsuKDCXG0NQm7BvAgx-c.ttf",
    "700": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/WDf5lZYgdmmKhO8E1AQud--Cz_5MeePnXDAcLNWyBME.ttf",
    "700italic": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/anonymouspro/v3/_fVr_XGln-cetWSUc-JpfA1LL9bfs7wyIp6F8OC9RxA.ttf"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Antic",
   "variants": [
    "regular"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "latin"
   ],
   "version": "v4",
   "lastModified": "2012-07-25",
   "files": {
    "regular": "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/antic/v4/hEa8XCNM7tXGzD0Uk0AipA.ttf"
   }
  },

[...]

]
}
```

You can do this offline (i.e. get the JSON once, and assume it does not update frequently), as part of your build step, or even dynamically (although that might be an overkill).

Comment: I've seen that google font api. but the documentation was going over my head! If you've any jsfiddle or working example anywhere, please show me.

Comment: I just looked again, the guide on the page is quite easy to follow. You need a Google account. You then request an API key. Paste that key at the end of the URL above, and you'll get the JSON file. You can try the API in the API explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/webfonts/v1/). You will need to know how to 1) make an AJAX request from your JavaScript code 2) parse the resulting JSON.

Comment: Actually, i don't have any experience on using with api. and also JSON data type. I even tried the following solution but getting error (used an api from google) ---  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757196/adding-google-font-api-to-select-menu/13757752#13757752