# Allow user to change font

Tags: angularjs, google-font-api, webfont-loader

I have an SVG with text that I am trying to let the user change with a select and options loaded in from google fonts. I am making an $http call to the google font api to get the list of the fonts and all the info that comes with it. I know about google webfontloader (although I am not sure quite how to implement it), but I am still having a difficult time getting the text to change to the appropriate selected font. I am using Angularjs.

For the question; How do I implement the info that I am getting from the API to allow the user to change the font?

Comment: Right off hand, you could add style="font-family:{{ selectedGoogleFont }};" in your element.

Comment: @Rob I have that like this for SVG; `<tspan ng-repeat="text in vm.NametagLines track by $index" ng-attr-font-family="{{text.Font}}" ng-attr-font-size="{{text.FontSize + 'pt'}}" ng-attr-fill="{{text.Color}}" ng-attr-x="{{vm.TextGroupMaster.X}}" ng-attr-dy="{{text.Y}}">{{vm.Lines[$index] || text.Label}}</tspan>`

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757196/adding-google-font-api-to-select-menu/57946077#57946077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working angular way to allow the user to change the font style using google api [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Maus/x6eq1Lyx/).

Here is some code since I can't post this answer without it.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

I used this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ENpWt/) as a starting point and changed it from pure javascript into angular.